# Is there a simple way to merge two objects?

Tags: javascript

lets say i have:

```
object1 = {
atk: 3,
def: 6,
hp: 4,
level: 17,
};

object2 = {
atk: 1,
def: 4,
hp: 2,
level: 10,
};
```

i want to multiply the two objects so i end up with

```
object3 = {
atk: 3, // 1 * 3
def: 24, // 4 * 6
hp: 8, // 2 * 4
level: 170, // 17 * 10
};
```

i tried like this

```
  let obj3 = {};
    obj3.atk = object1.atk * object2.atk;
    obj3.def= object1.def * object2.def;
    //etc....
```

but not sure if there's some simpler way since there are more keys/values than I've listed here.

Comment: Just iterate over the keys? Did you try?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to unpack a source object (e.g. `object1`), and the map through it to multiple its values with the corresponding value obtained by using `key` as an accessor on `object2`.

Once that is done it is a matter of using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert the `[key, value]` tuples back into an object:

```js
const object1 = {
  atk: 3,
  def: 6,
  hp: 4,
  level: 17,
};

const object2 = {
  atk: 1,
  def: 4,
  hp: 2,
  level: 10,
};

const object3 = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object1).map(([key, value]) => {
  value *= object2[key];
  return [key, value];
}));

console.log(object3);
```

Comment: Amazing thanks, so many good answers here :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most elegant way to do it is using the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) array method, mixed with the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function, which returns an array containing the keys of the object:

```js
const object1 = { atk: 3, def: 6, hp: 4, level: 17, };
const object2 = { atk: 1, def: 4, hp: 2, level: 10 };

const object3 = Object.keys(object1).reduce((result, key) => {
  result[key] = object1[key] * object2[key];
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(object3);
```

Comment: "Most elegant" is opinion based and leaves behind the question of performances.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a helper function that does pretty much the same as the previous answers:

```
const multiplyObjectsByKeys = (a, b) => Object.keys(a).reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: a[key] * b[key] }), {})

const object3 = multiplyObjectsByKeys(object1, object2)
```

In case you are using lodash in your project, you could also do it like this:

```
_.assignWith(object1, object2, (a, b) => a * b)
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks simple enough. I've had a friend recommend lodash before for other reasons, so I'll keep a note of it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest (code complexity) solutions would probably be using a simple [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, iterating over the keys of the fist object.

```js
const object1 = { atk: 3, def: 6, hp: 4, level: 17 };
const object2 = { atk: 1, def: 4, hp: 2, level: 10 };

const obj3 = {};
for (const key in object1) {
  obj3[key] = object1[key] * object2[key];
}

console.log(obj3);
```

This does assume that `object1` and `object2` both have the same keys.

Comment: Thanks! I initially attempted a for loop, but since I couldn't access them via index I didn't know where to go.